# How do I interpolate the value in certain data point by array of known points?

Tags: javascript, arrays, linear-interpolation

I have known data points and their values described as arrays, `speed` and `power`

```js
speed = [2, 6, 8, 10, 12]
power = [200, 450, 500, 645, 820],
```

I want to estimate the power value that corresponds to speed value (e.g. 7) that is not listed within source array (2 through 12).

I.e. I am seeking a way to perform interpolation

Answer (score 6):

The simplest way to do that is to [approximate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piecewise_linear_function) your power-from-speed dependency by the series of linear segments.

Assuming your target point (C) falls between two known points (A and B) on a certain segment you may calculate the value using [linear interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation) method.

[image]

[image]

Codewise, it will look as follows:

```js
const speed = [2, 6, 8, 10, 12], power = [200, 450, 500, 645, 820]
        
const interpolate = (xarr, yarr, xpoint) => {
    const   xa = [...xarr].reverse().find(x => x<=xpoint),
            xb = xarr.find(x => x>= xpoint),      
            ya = yarr[xarr.indexOf(xa)],      
            yb =yarr[xarr.indexOf(xb)]  
    return yarr[xarr.indexOf(xpoint)] || ya+(xpoint-xa)*(yb-ya)/(xb-xa)
}

console.log(interpolate(speed,power,7))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%}
```

Comment: Resultin power should be between 450 and 500, your result is 575

Comment: long time ago, I learnt that here `(yc-ya)/(xc-xa)` would be `tan(alpha)` not `sin(alpha)`, but this doesn't change your correct final equation for `yc`.

Comment: @theozh Thanks for pointing this out. Corrected.