# Update plotly plot without R/shiny's plotlyProxy

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, plotly

I’m working on an app in R/shiny where users should draw trajectories over time. Based on [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64309573/freehand-drawing-ggplot-how-to-improve-and-or-format-for-plotly)  [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41701807/way-to-free-hand-draw-shapes-in-shiny), I could cobble together a working example using a mix of shiny and plotly, but it is slow when deployed on the shiny server.

As far as I’ve understood, plotly interactive plots are fast because plotly works on the client side, while interactive plots with shiny have to transmit data between client and server. Indeed, the [freehand-drawing option in plotly](https://plotly.com/r/shapes/) has none of the lags I’m experiencing with my own attempts.

I’d like to speed up my app by eventually doing all data processing steps in JavaScript on the client side, then update the plotly plot without sending data to the shiny server first. Currently, I’m struggling with the latter – how can I update the data underlying the plotly plot using JavaScript alone?

**Example App:**

```
#Load packages
library(plotly)
library(shiny)
library(htmlwidgets)



################################################################################
#UI function
ui <- fixedPage(
  
      plotlyOutput("myPlot", width = 500, height = 250)
      
) #End UI






################################################################################
#Server function
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  js <- "
function(el, x){
      var id = el.getAttribute('id');
      var gd = document.getElementById(id);
      
      
      //Function to find unique indices in array, adapted from
      //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71922585/find-position-of-all-unique-elements-in-array
      function uniqueIndices(arr) {
      const seen = new Set();
      const indices = [];
      for (const [i, n] of arr.entries()) {
              if (!seen.has(n)) {
                  seen.add(n);
                  indices.push(i);
              }
          }
          return indices;
      }
      


      //Adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64309573/freehand-drawing-ggplot-how-to-improve-and-or-format-for-plotly
      Plotly.update(id).then(attach);
        function attach() {
          gd.on('plotly_relayout', function(evt) {


            //Save most recent shape from plotly
            var output = gd.layout.shapes[0];
            
            //Only retain the path for further processing
            var path = output.path;
            
            //Transform path into x/y coordinates
            //Points in the path start with 'M' or 'L' - use this to split the string
            var path = path.replace(/M|L/g, ',');
            var path = path.split(',');
            
            //Remove empty first element
            var path = path.slice(1);
            
            //Define as numeric
            var path = path.map(Number);
            
            
            
            
            //x values are saved at odd indices, y values at even indices
            //Create x indices
            var xIndex = [];
            xIndex.length = (path.length / 2);
            
            for (let i =0; i <= path.length - 1; i+= 2) {
            xIndex.push(i);
            }
            


           //Create y indices
            var yIndex = [];
            yIndex.length = (path.length / 2);
            
            for (let i =1; i <= path.length; i+= 2) {
            yIndex.push(i);
            }
            
            
            
            
            //Now, separate path into x and y values
            var xPath = xIndex.map(i=>path[i]);
            var yPath = yIndex.map(i=>path[i]);
            
            //Only allow integer values for x axis
            var xPath = xPath.map(item => Math.round(item))

            //After rounding to integers, x values might be duplicated
            //Retain only one value per x coordinate
            var yPath = uniqueIndices(xPath).map(i=>yPath[i])
            var xPath = uniqueIndices(xPath).map(i=>xPath[i]);






            //Current approach sends these values to shiny, then adds a new trace via plotlyProxy
            Shiny.setInputValue('shinyX', xPath);
            Shiny.setInputValue('shinyY', yPath);
            
            
            //Remove previous shapes so that only the most recent line is visible
            gd.update_layout(gd.layout.shapes = output)
          });
        };
  }
  "
  
  
  
  
  #Plotly plot
  output$myPlot <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(type = "scatter", mode = "markers") %>% 
      
      plotly::layout(
        dragmode = "drawopenpath",
        newshape = list(line = list(color = "gray50")),
        
        #x axis
        xaxis = list(title = "x",
                     fixedrange = TRUE,
                     range = c(-0.1, 10.1),
                     showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showline = TRUE, mirror = TRUE),
        
        #y axis
        yaxis = list(title = "y",
                     fixedrange = TRUE,
                     range = c(1.1, 5.1),
                     showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showline = TRUE, mirror = TRUE)) %>% 
      
    #Call js
    onRender(js) 

  }) #End render plotly
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  #Create plotlyProxy object 
  myPlotProxy <- plotlyProxy("myPlot", session)
  
  
  
  
  
  
  ################################################################################
  #Observe drawn user input
  observe({    
    
    #Ensure that user input is not NULL
    if(!is.null(input$shinyY))
    {
      #Delete existing traces
      plotlyProxyInvoke(myPlotProxy, "deleteTraces", {
        list(0) 
      })
      
      
      #Add user-drawn line based on new coordinates
      plotlyProxyInvoke(myPlotProxy, "addTraces", {
        list(list(x = input$shinyX,
                  y = input$shinyY,
                  hoverinfo = "none",
                  mode = "lines+markers"))
      })
      
    } #End condition that user input must not be NULL
  }) #End observe for drawn user input
} #End server function





################################################################################
#Execute app
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The example above uses plotly’s drawopenpath to draw a line. The path is converted to x/y coordinates, and I want the x coordinates to be integer values, e.g. 0, 1, 2 etc. At the moment, these coordinates are send to the shiny server, which then uses plotlyProxy to update the plot.

I suspect that this back and forth makes the app so slow, i.e. there is a 0.5 – 1 second lag between drawing and the plot getting updated. This does not happen when running the app locally. So, is there any way to update the plotly plot with new values without sending data to the shiny server first? I have played around with update_layout, but couldn't get it to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I just run your example app and it doesn't seem to be slow at all? However, if you'd like to avoid passing the coordinates to shiny you'll need to use plotly's [JS functions](https://plotly.com/javascript/plotlyjs-function-reference/#plotlyaddtraces) directly in your `onRender` call. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71235197/9841389) you can find a similar approach. Furthermore, you might want to check the {profvis} package to profile your app.

Comment: Hi, indeed the app works well when run locally on my computer; the delay only happens when deploying it on the shiny server. Thank you very much for the suggested question, I will check out if I can get this approach to work in my example.

Comment: Have you been able to work out a solution for this, based on my input?

Comment: Indeed, I got a working solution based on your example in the linked question (and quite a bit of trial and error). I will add it later during the weekend when I got a little more time on my hands. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the suggestions of @ismirsehregal and the helpful examples in the linked question and beyond, I managed to build a working app that does not need shiny for processing input and updating the user-drawn line. And indeed, the lagged reaction to user input is gone when deploying this app to my shiny server!

The new code is shown below. I don't have any previous experience with Javascript, so this code might make more experienced users weep. However, it does work well for my purposes and might be helpful for others, so please bear with me. ;)

```
#Load packages
library(plotly)
library(shiny)
library(htmlwidgets)



################################################################################
#UI function
ui <- fixedPage(
  
  plotlyOutput("myPlot", width = 500, height = 250),
  
  
  #Temporary grey line when actively drawing (will disappear when users stop drawing by setting color to transparent later)
  #see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77538320/plotly-drawopenpath-color-of-finished-line-vs-drawing-in-process
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML("
      .select-outline {
        stroke: rgb(150, 150, 150) !important;
        }"))),
  
) #End UI






################################################################################
#Server function
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  js <- "
function(el, x){

      //Function to find unique indices in array, adapted from
      //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71922585/find-position-of-all-unique-elements-in-array
      function uniqueIndices(arr) {
      const seen = new Set();
      const indices = [];
      for (const [i, n] of arr.entries()) {
              if (!seen.has(n)) {
                  seen.add(n);
                  indices.push(i);
              }
          }
          return indices;
      }
      

      //Function for linear interpolation between points given as two arrays 
      //adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59264119/how-do-i-interpolate-the-value-in-certain-data-point-by-array-of-known-points
      const interpolate = (xarr, yarr, xpoint) => {
        const   xa = [...xarr].reverse().find(x => x<=xpoint),
                xb = xarr.find(x => x>= xpoint),      
                ya = yarr[xarr.indexOf(xa)],      
                yb =yarr[xarr.indexOf(xb)]  
        return yarr[xarr.indexOf(xpoint)] || ya+(xpoint-xa)*(yb-ya)/(xb-xa)
            };





      //Define eligible integer x values for the user-drawn line
      var xLimits = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
      
      //y values are empty at first and will be filled with user-drawn coordinates
      var yValues = new Array(xLimits.length).fill('');
      


      var id = el.getAttribute('id');
      var gd = document.getElementById(id);
      

      //Main function
      //Adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64309573/freehand-drawing-ggplot-how-to-improve-and-or-format-for-plotly
      Plotly.update(id).then(attach);
        function attach() {

          //Check changes following relayout event
          gd.on('plotly_relayout', function(evt) {
          
            //Save most recent shape from plotly
            var output = gd.layout.shapes[0];
            
            //Only retain the path for further processing
            var path = output.path;
            
            //Transform path into x/y coordinates
            //Points in the path start with 'M' or 'L' - use this to split the string
            path = path.replace(/M|L/g, ',');
            path = path.split(',');
            
            //Remove empty first element
            path = path.slice(1);
            
            //Define as numeric
            path = path.map(Number);
            
 
            
            
            //x values are saved at odd indices, y values at even indices
            //Create x indices
            var xIndex = [];
            xIndex.length = (path.length / 2);
            
            for (let i =0; i <= path.length - 1; i+= 2) {
            xIndex.push(i);
            }
            


           //Create y indices
            var yIndex = [];
            yIndex.length = (path.length / 2);
            
            for (let i =1; i <= path.length; i+= 2) {
            yIndex.push(i);
            }
            
            
            //Now, separate path into x and y values
            var xPath = xIndex.map(i=>path[i]);
            var yPath = yIndex.map(i=>path[i]);


            //Only allow integer values for x axis
            xPath = xPath.map(item => Math.round(item));

            //After rounding to integers, x values might be duplicated
            //Retain only one value per x coordinate
            yPath = uniqueIndices(xPath).map(i=>yPath[i]);
            xPath = uniqueIndices(xPath).map(i=>xPath[i]);


            //Create 2 new placeholders for x/y coordinates
            //The goal is to take the existing path and fill 'holes' in it: The SVG path does not necessarily
            //have x/y coordinates for all values on the x axis. If e.g. a straight line from x1 = 1 to x2 = 5
            //is enough, the SVG path will only include these end points, but no points in between. To get a full
            //set of x/y coordinates, interpolation will be used
            var placeholderX = [];
            var placeholderY = [];

            
            //Interpolation function was defined above
            //The loop covers the whole range of the x axis, but the interpolate function returns only values
            //for the given x/y values at the i-th value of the x axis limits. For instance, if the axis limits are
            //0:10, and the input coordinates for x are 3, 6, 7, then the function will return values for 3:7
            for(let i = xLimits[0]; i < xLimits.length; i++) {
            placeholderY.push(interpolate(xPath, yPath, i));
            }

            //Save corresponding x values after interpolation
            //The loop above returns y values, while this loop creates an equal number of x values
            //It loops from the smallest value in xPath to the largest and saves all integer values inbetween
            //Since users can draw from left to right or right to left, the starting point for the loop is always
            //the minimum of the x coordinates and the end point is the maximum
            for(let i = Math.min(...[xPath[1], xPath[xPath.length - 1]]); 
                i < Math.max(...[xPath[1], xPath[xPath.length - 1]]);     i++) {
            placeholderX.push(i)
            }

            //Last index seems to be missing; add it
            placeholderX.push(1 + Math.max(...placeholderX));


            //Ensure that input has at least 2 entries so that a line can be drawn (not only a point)
            if(placeholderX.length > 1) {
            
             //Loop over entries in prepared, interpolated placeholder
             //The interpolated y coordinates are added to the final dataset at the position determined by the x coordinate placeholder
                for(let i = Math.min(...placeholderX); 
                    i <= Math.max(...placeholderX); i++) {
                yValues[i] = placeholderY[i];
                    }
            }
 

            //Remove previous shapes so that only the most recent line is visible
            Plotly.deleteTraces(gd, 0);
            Plotly.addTraces(gd, {x: xLimits, y: yValues, 
                                  line: {color: 'red'},
                                  hoverinfo: 'none',
                                  mode: 'lines+markers',
                                  }, 0);
            gd.update_layout(gd.layout.shapes = output);
          });
        };
  }
  " #End JS part
  
  
  
  
  
  
  #Plotly plot
  output$myPlot <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(type = "scatter", mode = "markers") %>% 
      
      plotly::layout(
        dragmode = "drawopenpath",
        newshape = list(line = list(color = "transparent")),
        
        #x axis
        xaxis = list(title = "x",
                     fixedrange = TRUE,
                     range = c(-0.1, 10.1),
                     showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showline = TRUE, mirror = TRUE),
        
        #y axis
        yaxis = list(title = "y",
                     fixedrange = TRUE,
                     range = c(1.1, 5.1),
                     showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showline = TRUE, mirror = TRUE)) %>% 
      
      #Call js
      onRender(js) 
    
  }) #End render plotly
  
  
} #End server function





################################################################################
#Execute app
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

One issue I had with previous attempts was that the line from plotly's drawopenpath was still visible after adding the processed coordinates to the plot via addTraces(). I hijacked the answer to my other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77538320/plotly-drawopenpath-color-of-finished-line-vs-drawing-in-process/77541982#77541982), which helped to sidestep this problem by making the finished line invisible. I guess there are more elegant solutions out there, but I'm completely happy with the behavior here. :)