# Plotly "drawopenpath" color of finished line vs. drawing-in-process

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I’m currently working on an R/shiny app where users can draw trajectories over time, using [plotly’s “drawopenpath” function](https://plotly.com/r/shapes/#drawing-shapes-on-cartesian-plots).

When users press the left mouse button and start drawing, the drawn line has a lighter color (e.g. dark grey instead of black). After stopping to draw (mouse up), the line gets its nominal color (e.g. black), as shown below:

[image: Line color when drawing is in process (dark grey):] [image: Line color of the finished line (black):]

I’m looking for a way to make this visual difference more noticeable, preferably by assigning different colors for the drawing process (e.g. light gray)) vs. the finished line (e.g. red). So far, I have only managed to change the color for both "steps", as shown below.

```
library(plotly)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
    plotlyOutput("myPlot", width = 500, height = 250)
    
  )



server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$myPlot <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(type = "scatter", mode = "markers") %>% 
      
      plotly::layout(
        dragmode = "drawopenpath",
        
        #This only changes the color of the whole line
        newshape = list(line = list(color = "black")))
  })
} 


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Is there any way to differentiate these two lines better, either by color or using a different parameter (maybe opacity)? I would be very grateful for any ideas or pointers in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

plotly temporarily adds a path having the same color as the final shape but using `opacity: 0.5` to its zoomlayer when using `drawopenpath`:

```
<g class="zoomlayer">
    <path class="select-outline select-outline-0 select-outline-xy cursor-move" style="opacity: 0.5; stroke: black; stroke-width: 4px;" fill-rule="evenodd" transform="translate(60,25)" d="M38,135Z"></path>
    <path class="zoombox-corners" style="fill: rgb(255, 255, 255); stroke: rgb(68, 68, 68); stroke-width: 1px;" transform="translate(60,25)" d="M0,0Z"></path>
</g>
```

We can [restyle it via css](https://shiny.posit.co/r/articles/build/css/):

```
library(plotly)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML("
      .select-outline {
        // opacity: 1;
        stroke: rgb(255, 0, 0) !important;
        // stroke-opacity: 1;
        // fill: rgb(0, 0, 0);
        // fill-opacity: 0;
        // stroke-width: 4px;
        // pointer-events: stroke;
      }"))
  ),
  plotlyOutput("myPlot", width = 500, height = 250)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$myPlot <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(type = "scatter", mode = "markers") %>% 
      
      plotly::layout(
        dragmode = "drawopenpath",
        
        # This only changes the color of the whole line
        newshape = list(line = list(color = "black")))
  })
} 

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: result]

Comment: Amazing, works like a charm! Thank you very much for your help here and on my previous question! :) I will update the latter with the solution I came up with following your suggestions.